# Enabling Wifi direct in Android 4.0

Tags: android, wifi

I have bought a new android 4.0.3 tablet- Micromax Funbook P300 to learn developing android applications.

I started with Wifi Direct, so that the tablet could be used as a remote for robotic platform.

To my disappointment the stock OS doesn't provide this function in the settings menu.

Is it possible to check if we can programatically start wifi direct feature?

If not can someone direct to some tutorials which addresses this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK contains a sample application for using the DirectWiFi mode:

[WiFiDirectDemo - Wi-Fi Direct Demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/index.html)

The used API itself is located in [android.net.wifi.p2p](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

WiFi Direct should be supported by Android 4.0.3 (it has been around since Android API 14, or Android 4.0). It is possible that your tablet does not support WiFi Direct due to a hardware limitation, but I doubt it. You probably aren't seeing it in the settings because there is a custom Android skin running on the tablet that prevents you from seeing it, or maybe the WiFi Direct settings interface wasn't implemented until Android 4.1 or something.

Whatever the case, you can test it easily in the code.

First, put the proper permissions in your manifest.xml

http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#permissions

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.nsdchat"
    ...

    <uses-permission
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    ...
```

Next, try initializing the Android WiFiP2pManager class to see if it is supported.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    WifiP2pManager manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    WifiP2pManager.Channel channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
}
```

Where I put null, you could pass a callback to check for failure. If it works, follow the rest of the [Wi-Fi Direct guide](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html) to create your app.

Answer (score -2):

He's not asking for a coded program example, so much as a way to programatically switch on the technology (ie one line of code). As far as I am aware there is no way to do this. It all has to be done from within your devices settings. While some devices allow Wi-Fi Direct to be switched on, other devices treat it the same as having regular Wi-Fi enabled - have you tried this? And have you checked if the P300 even supports Wi-Fi Direct?

Comment: a coded program example will show you how to use wifi direct. no, it's not possible to use wifi direct in one line of code, but it's definitely possible to try using wifi direct using the api, then see if it is supported or not, given the log messages. the other answer is much more useful.